# Ruby: Convert CIDR to Netmask

Tags: ruby, ip-address, subnet, cidr, netmask

Given a network definition like `192.168.1.0/24`, I'd like to convert the `/24` CIDR to a four digit netmask, in this case `255.255.255.0`.

No extra gems should be used.

Answer (score 2):

The actual method here is pretty simple:

```rb
def mask(n)
  [ ((1 << 32) - 1) << (32 - n) ].pack('N').bytes.join('.')
end
```

Where that can give you results like:

```rb
mask(24)
# => "255.255.255.0"
mask(16)
# => "255.255.0.0"
mask(22)
# => "255.255.252.0"
```

Comment: For people not accustomed to bit shifting, the constant value method `((1<<32)-1)` is equivalent to `(256**4 - 1)` or `4294967295`. It is a 4-Byte integer containing all ones when expressed in binary. When shifting this value according to the mask, the ones are shifted to the left and are replaced by zeros which is then formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's `IPAddr` does not appear to expose this functionality. However, it contains a private instance variable called `@mask_addr` that contains the integer value of the desired mask.

It can be represented as a four digit submask by converting it back to another `IPAddr` instance:

```rb
require "ipaddr"

net = IPAddr.new("192.168.1.0/24")
subnet = IPAddr.new(net.instance_variable_get(:@mask_addr), Socket::AF_INET).to_s
# => "255.255.255.0"
```

Comment: How does `net`, which is a string here, have an instance variable?